# Beginner C# programming, fill array with user input but not using for loop

Tags: c#, arrays

Fill array with user input but not using `for` loop, because the user need to select when to enter the data.
`for` loop will not be useful here because I'm not trying to let the user enter all the input at once, but when the user chooses to via switch statement.

I don't know if this makes any sense, new here, excuse my unprofessional language.

```
static void AddChemical(string[] ChemicalName, string[] Supplier, int[] YearPurchased, int[] Toxicty, int[] Flammability, int[] Corrosiveness, int[] Explosive, int[] Harmful, int[] Overall, float[] Quantity, float[] Cost)
{
    int Count = 0;
    Count = Count + 1;

    Console.Write("Enter the name of the Chemical: ");
    ChemicalName[Count] = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter the year it was Purchased: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out YearPurchased[Count]);

    Console.Write("Enter the Supplier of the Chemical: ");
    Supplier[Count] = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter the Quantity of the Chemical in (L/Kg): ");
    float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Quantity[Count]);

    Console.Write("Enter the cost of the Chemical: ");
    float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Cost[Count]);

    Console.Write("Enter the Toxicty of the Chemical: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Toxicty[Count]);

    Console.Write("Enter the Flammability of the Chemical: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Flammability[Count]);

    Console.Write("Enter the Corrosiveness of the chemical: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Corrosiveness[Count]);

    Console.Write("Enter the Explosive of the Chemical: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Explosive[Count]);

    Console.Write("Enter the Harmful of the Chemical: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Harmful[Count]);
}
```

This method is inside a `switch` statement.

Comment: Voting to close, you do not explain what need help with

Comment: I don't see any switch statement. and for loop can be useful here. you just don't know how to do it. leave aside your prejudice

Comment: Alright, sorry boys first time here, new to programming, don't know how to use the correct words, man I need to work on how to explain things better.

Comment: Looks like you are entering data related to a product. Unless this is a class where you have learned about arrays but not about compound types (classes), your method should use a class holding all the product properties, and fill these with the user inputs. Your outer method (whether it uses a for loop, a switch statememt, or whatever), can then simply use an array or list of this class. Much better than using a boatload of arrays. And if you need concrete help, tell us (a) what the problem is, (b) what code you already wrote to resolve it, (c) where in particular you are stuck/need help with.

Answer (score 0):

I Really Have no idea what you are trying to do, but if you are talking about entering all the inputs into a array but not in the same time you can use collections.

first you need to use the nampspace

`using System.Collections`

Then Create a new Collection that holds on your results

```
ArrayList dataHolder = new ArrayList();
```

Then Whenever you need to add Something to it just type this code

```
dataHolder.Add("We are adding a string");
dataHolder.Add(21) // Adding a Number
```

and you can get them letter by index

```
Console.WriteLine(dataHolder[1]); // Outputs 21
```

BTW this is really non-efficient way of writing the code but i am just helping you out ;)